# Programmatically discover the name of the .DMG

Tags: objective-c

say I have a .DMG
I click it to open it
there's an app inside.
I run the app (which I develop)

Is there a programatic way for the executable to find out the name of the .DMG it's running from at runtime (if any)? perhaps a "Get full path" which will include the name of that DMG? There are certain keywords on that .DMG name that may exist and if they do, I need to act upon them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundlePath]; //Or Bundle URL, depends if you prefer NSString or NSURL.
```